# How can I make CEX work for plot?

Tags: r, plot

Consider the following example.

```
pdf("Test.pdf")

plot(1:23, 2:24, type="l", col="blue", main="Test Title", xlab="# of Clients", ylab="Throughput (kops/sec)",ylim=c(1,27), cex=2)
lines(1:23, 3:25, col="red")

legend(1, 300, c("First Line","Second Line"), lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("blue","red"))

dev.off()
```

When I adjust the CEX parameter from 2 to 1 or 3, I expect all the text to change in size, but nothing happens.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: see `?par` particualry, `cex.main`, `cex.axis` `cex.lab` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cex` parameter only applies to plotted *symbols*, and you are drawing lines and annotations.

To change the size of text in annotations use `cex.axis` and friends, see `help(par)` for more.

For the `pdf` driver you might get some joy with the `pointsize` parameter: eg `pdf("foo.pdf",pointsize=20)`. See `help(pdf)` for more options.